# Remove if-modified-since header from okhttp request

Tags: android, http-headers, okhttp

okhttp sends both `if-modified-since` date and `if-none-match` checksum headers in requests. There's usually no need for both and `if-none-match` is enough to figure out the version the client has. Sending both just confuses some http/1.1 server implementations

I have tried

```
builder = new Request.Builder().removeHeader("if-modified-since");
```

But that doesn't seem to do it. I assume the header is added later.

Is there a way to tell okhttp not to send `if-modified-since` ?

Comment: This is a bug. Tracking here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1354

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can in builder.
You basically need to rebuild your request. Here is a complete sample:

```
   httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest = chain
                    .request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader("if-modified-since")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    });
```